# Golang Server shutdown using context unnecessarily?

Tags: go, signals

I'm going through Nic Jackson's tutorial on Youtube and he has the following code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "microservice/handlers"
)

func main() {
    l := log.New(os.Stdout, "product-api", log.LstdFlags)

    hh := handlers.NewHello(l)
    gh := handlers.NewGoodbye(l)

    sm := http.NewServeMux()
    sm.Handle("/", hh)
    sm.Handle("/goodbye", gh)

    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":9000",
        Handler:      sm,
        IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  1 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }

    go func() {
        err := s.ListenAndServe()
        if err != nil {
            l.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Kill)

    sig := <-sigChan
    l.Println("Received terminate, graceful shutdown", sig)

    tc, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    s.Shutdown(tc)
}
```

I'm totally confused by the last few lines here after the go routine is kicked off. I generally understand that he's creating listeners for os.Interrupt and os.Kill and then `sig := <-sigChan` is basically a blocking call (right?). But what is the context for?

He creates a context with timeout, and passes it into `s.Shutdown()`. Why is the context necessary and what is it doing? Could you equally validly just do `s.Shutdown(context.Background())` The context didn't do anything else or provide any other information to the server. Doesn't s.Shutdown() do what we need (i.e. close the server)?

I've looked at other tutorials about Contexts and I think I generally get what they are for, but I don't see it being used to pass data down to other goroutines, or even the goroutine created here.

Comment: The context has a 30 second timeout, for the purpose of calling `Shutdown` with a 30 second time, that is all.

Comment: @JimB so what does that mean in practical terms? If I run the code and don't do anything, the server will close automatically after 30 seconds?

Comment: No, the code tries to wait for a signal (incorrectly, the channel must be buffered, and you can't handle a SIGKILL) before shutting down the server.